# java many threads writing random bytes to file simultaneously [just need advice]

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, file-writing

I am writing a simple benchmark of sorts in java to test parallelization. The program generates 1000 random bytes in total and writes them to a binary file. It uses different amounts of threads to parallelize the byte generation and writing to disk, and measures the execution time of the overall process for each thread count.

The program splits the *entirety* of the execution among a specified number of threads - both the generation of byte arrays **and** the writing of these bytes to a file.

My problem is, I need to have a single binary file at the end. I need advice as far as how best to make each thread write its trash bytes to the same file. Keep in mind I do not care at all what order they end up in. I have three ideas so far:

1) Should I have each thread create an instance of RandomAccessFile each referencing the same empty file on the disk, and have each thread write to the file starting from a different location in a way that they do not overlap? This seems like the best way to truly parallelize the disk writing.

2) Can I pass each thread a reference to some kind of buffered stream object and have each thread send its byte array into this stream? Is there a way to create an object which will just listen for bytes and immediately write them to a file in whatever order it receives them? I am worried that having a single object collect all of the bytes would not truly represent parallelized disk writing.

3) Should I have each thread write its bytes to its own file, and then "merge" its file into the main file?

Thanks for your time! I don't need detailed code examples, just want to get some advice as I work on this to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Create `FileOutputStream`, get corresponding [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and write data using [ByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).